# Windward ASP.net example cannot find KeyPairDictionary and IReportDataSource

Tags: windward

I am trying to run the ASP.net example that can be found on windward website. But it wont build because of the errors.
It can not find KeyPairDictionary
It can not find IReportDataSource

What do I need to add in my code to make it run?

Thanks.

Comment: check your using statements and make sure you are referencing the correct assemblies

Comment: found one using statement that resolved IReportDataSource. Cant find one for KeyPairDictionary

Answer (score 0):

The KeyPairDictionary class was deprecated and is no longer in use. Please take a look at [Upgrading to the 12.5 API](http://wiki.windward.net/Wiki/05.NET_Engine/06.FAQ/Upgrading_to_the_12.5_API) for details.